# How do I add horizontal margins to my WPF TabItems without cutting off the tab?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

My TabItems before attempting to apply a left margin of 10 look like:

[image]

After attempting to apply the left margin of 10 to the blue tab, the blue tab gets cut off like:

[image]

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Can you post the control template you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this but easiest thing to do is to simply customize the TabItem.Header content like so:

```
    <TabControl Margin="29,29,25,23" Name="tabControl1">
        <TabItem Name="tabItem1">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,20,0">tabItem1</TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem  Name="tabItem2">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,20,0">tabItem2</TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tabItem3" Name="tabItem3">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

If you were planning on doing this for every tab, and you probably should, I'd consider using a style to apply these margins.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you have a Width set on the blue tab. When you add a margin part of the width is taken up by the margin so part of the tab gets cut off. Remove the Width attribute and try to use Padding instead.

Comment: There are no widths set on anything.